# Query with Time in Parse iOS Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, parse-platform

In my Parse database, it having a column as Time, so the data of it is (**08:30 - 10:30**) *just for an example. It is the String value, since the Parse doesn't support for the Date Time.
What if I want to query the time which is 09:00, how should I query this?
I'm trying to do like this...

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Timetable")
query.wherekey("Time".substringToIndex(advance(1,5)), greatherThanOrEqualTo: "09:00")
```

But it doesn't work and showing error as well, how should I query it so that it can validate 09:00 is in the middle of that time?

[image: You can see the example of my Parse Class here, the Time is look like that, what if I want to query is my time is in the middle of that time duration?]
[image]

You can see the example of my Parse Class here, the Time is look like that, what if I want to query is my time is in the middle of that time duration?

Comment: @nhgrif that `08:30 - 10:30` is already fixed by CSV file, I just import the CSV file and try to grab all the data, so I want to make the query with this time, so how do I query and get the 09:00 (this time is just an example)

Comment: @nhgrif I try to printscreen my Parse database so you guys can have a look on it. Just don't care about the CSV, because I've imported the CSV file into the Parse database already.

Answer (score 0):

Its a shame that parse doesn't support importation of dates via CSV, but the database supports date types, and it seems that's what you need.

I would perform a function after the import to parse the string column and create dates.  From the strings in the question, it looks like the object needs start date and end date attributes.  Maybe duration would be handy also.

The benefits of doing this are (a) the dates can be represented unambiguously as UTC, (b) you'll have a chance to query on them, including inequalities like greaterThan, lessThan.

Comment: If the String was like this **08:30 - 10:30** , if I want to query it like 08:30 is lessThan 09:00, AND 10:30 is greaterThan 09:00, is it possible I can do like this? I get the String index value like 08:30 is from 0 index to index 4, so in this index I use it to compare with 09:00?

Comment: You'll need to bring all of the records into memory, then go through, doing string computation in order to match.  I don't see any alternative to converting to real date/time.

Comment: Is it possible to covert this String **08:30 - 10:30** to the Time format? like I get the 08:30 hh:mm as the time format, so I compare it with the current time for example 09:00, so I validate it by using 08:30 lessThan 09:00 and 10:30 is greaterThan 09:00